# Open Multiple instances of the same file in Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, multiple-instances

Is there any way to open multiple instances of the same file in Word 2007?

Currently, if I open a second instance of the file, the focus shifts to the file which is already open.

The "split" functionality isn't of much use either. - since I often need to refer more than 2 documents and even with just documents, it's just too much of scrolling required.

A crude workaround is to rename the file to something like `file-1`,`file-2`,`file-3` but isn't really practical.

Comment: Presumably you don't want to edit in both?  Perhaps open the doc read-only in wordpad.

Comment: @Paul yes, no editing required, just read-only as a reference

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go under View and press New Window.

Comment: Yeah, it's on my quickaccess bar.  I had to figure out where it is by default.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you're looking for is the document split view. This lets you view two separate parts of the same document. To turn it on go to the View tab, and click Split. [Source](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/top-tips-for-word-2007-HA010206594.aspx#BM5).

Comment: I've mentioned in the question "The "split" functionality isn't of much use either.".

Comment: Oops, my bad, I didn't notice that. Can you clarify why the split functionality doesn't work for you?

Comment: I have updated the question as to why split doesn't work out for me. Thanks